# Team Foundation Server How to Edit file without checking it out

Tags: tfs

i'm working with TFS and i need to edit file localy without checking it out .
another case if some one checked in the file and i need to change my locally copy.

what should I do  ?
in Visual source safe we can do that by removing the read only check on the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well.. You can certainly unmark the file as read only and edit it in something other than visual studio.  Or, you can still use visual studio, but not edit it when the solution it's a part of is opened..

Quite frankly, I'd look into other options with regards to why 
1. that file needs to be in source control.
2. If it does need to be in source control, why does *your* copy need to be different.

Comment: It's the web.config file, and I'm working in a different database

Comment: Then you should look into section replacement of config files.  This can be kicked off whenever you execute the project.  That way you don't have to worry about other peoples sections.

Comment: @AmRoSH: try this http://blog.andreloker.de/post/2008/06/Keep-your-config-clean-with-external-config-files.aspx

Comment: @Ram: Fantastic link for how to do this.  @AmRoSH: Just don't check in your local copies of the config sections and you won't have to worry about stepping on each others toes.

Comment: @Chris If you're talking about web.config transforms, those only come into effect whenever deployed.  When run locally, even if you select that build configuration, they are not used.

Comment: I can actually think of all sorts of reasons you may want to edit a file outside of source control.  Testing theoretical changes, testing possible forks prior to actually forking the code base, making one of changes to test a specific scenario, et cetera.

Comment: "unmark the file as read only and edit it in something other than visual studio" worked well

Comment: Cached link from @NotMe's comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20161122191325/http://blog.andreloker.de/post/2008/06/Keep-your-config-clean-with-external-config-files.aspx

Answer (score 32):

Ok, this is relatively easy in VS2010, and quite normal.  I mean the locking model of source control is obsolete anyway.

In vs2010, click **Tools** -> **Options** -> **Source Control** -> **Environment** and select **Allow checked-in items to be edited**. This should stop the TF client from marking files as read-only.

Also you may have to change the **Editing** drop-down in **Source Control** -> **Environment** to **Do nothing**.

Comment: Having dealt with merging in subversion and others I can assure you that the locking model is far from dead.

Comment: @ChrisLively: Merges are the pits, but locking can lead to ridiculous problems as well.

Comment: THANK YOU! This was driving me nuts, and your comment is the *only* answer I came across.  Thanks again.  Can you please elaborate on what you mean by where you say "locking model of source control is obsolete anyway"?  Thanks.

Comment: @Toddintr: I just think that merging tools have reached the point where two people should be able to work on the same file.  TFS is based on microsoft's Visual Source Safe which is based on the open source CVS.  CVS was made obsolete by SVN, because it allowed two developers to work on the same file and merge them later.  Because TFS is based on VSS which is based on the obsoleted CVS, it follows that the TFS locking model is obsolete.

Comment: I have worked with merging in TFS and have never had any problems.  I only navigate conflicts and read them carefully, which are rare, as most are auto merged.  Merging project files usually involves selecting both lines from both left and right.  The only time the project should be locked is for moving files, in which case you should notify other developers to do a get once you check in.  Also, do gets as often as possible will maximize your chances of using automerge.  Even if you have to go awhile without a get, navigating conflicts is not a pain IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Just unset the read-only flag on the file locally.

You may have some issues later when try to do a "Get Latest" operation, which will warn you about a locally writeable file.