# Why can't I open a task of a read-only .dtsx file?

Tags: tfs, ssis, task

We are using TFS and we have a SSIS project with exclusive checkout.
A colleague has a file F.dtsx in checkout.
I open with VS2015 the F.dtsx and I can correctly see the Control Flow.
When I try to open a task, it asks me to take F.dtsx in checkout and of course I can't. So I can't see what's in the task even if I just want to READ it.

How can I do?

Thanks

Comment: Answer on [Team Foundation Server How to Edit file without checking it out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5966678/205233) should still work with VS 2015.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I guess that answer you quote does not apply to my case and asks me to to things I don't want to do (changing the policy of editing files that MUST NOT be edited).
As I said in the post, I need to be able to just READ a file that is in READONLY. I don't want to modify it.

Comment: I'm afraid your stuck with how .dtsx files behave - just opening a task/functoid modifies the file and I don't think there's a way to get around this.

Comment: In this case, thank you for this piece of information. I didn't know that and it explains the source of my problem.

Comment: On a side note, I don't understand why downvoting this question. The problem I have is wasting my time and it would be USEFUL to find a solution. I SEARCHED on Google and here for a solution and I didn't find anything. I presume it is also quite clearly stated. So why the "-1"?

Comment: Didn't DV (only removed the [tag:readonly] tag because it's marked "DO NOT USE")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the F.dtsx package to another package and open that. You'd have control of it. You can undo your checkout when you're done.

Answer (score 1):

The file is locked with your colleague. So, if you don't want to change your current process, you need to ask your colleague to release the file.

Or, you can try to unlock the file, reference below thread:

- [Eclipse TFS check out error can't show file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45347871/eclipse-tfs-check-out-error-cant-show-file)
- [How to unlock a file from someone else in Team Foundation Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451637/how-to-unlock-a-file-from-someone-else-in-team-foundation-server)

If you just need to read, just as Rich said, get a copy to read.